# How to calculate age with years or months or days base on todays date and date of birth field in rdlc?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working with Registration Certificate which needed the age of the baby it could be years,months,or days. I used `= DateDiff("YYYY",Fields!IssuedOnORNo.Value, Fields!CertificationDate.Value)` but it only produces years same when i change it to month or day. What I want is it will compute the age of the child whether when it is a month old or a days old.

Comment: your function syntax is not Sql Server

Comment: edit: = DateDiff("YYYY",Fields!DateofBirth.Value, Fields!CertificationDate.Value) not the code above. Sorry wrong copied code. And yes it is not sql server but vb code in RDLC report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kindly try the t-sql code below if it works:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.RegistrationCertificate (IssuedOnORNo DATETIME, CertificationDate DATETIME)

INSERT dbo.RegistrationCertificate (IssuedOnORNo, CertificationDate)
SELECT GETDATE(), DATEADD(MONTH, 13, GETDATE())
UNION ALL
SELECT GETDATE(), GETDATE() + 1
UNION ALL
SELECT GETDATE() - 2, GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT GETDATE(), DATEADD(YEAR, 3, GETDATE())
UNION ALL
SELECT GETDATE(), DATEADD(MONTH, 4, GETDATE())

SELECT t.*
    , YEARS = DATEDIFF(YEAR, t.IssuedOnORNo, t.CertificationDate)
    , MONTHS = (DATEDIFF(MONTH, t.IssuedOnORNo, t.CertificationDate) - ((DATEDIFF(MONTH, t.IssuedOnORNo, t.CertificationDate) / 12) * 12))
    , DAYS = ((DATEDIFF(DAY, t.IssuedOnORNo, t.CertificationDate) - ((DATEDIFF(DAY, t.IssuedOnORNo, t.CertificationDate) / 365) * 365))
        - (((DATEDIFF(MONTH, t.IssuedOnORNo, t.CertificationDate) - ((DATEDIFF(MONTH, t.IssuedOnORNo, t.CertificationDate) / 12) * 12))) * 30) - 1)
FROM dbo.RegistrationCertificate  t WITH(NOLOCK)
```

btw roger, in case you're wondering how to use that code in your report, you may create a stored procedure for your report data using the code above.

EDIT:

in that case the code below should be a close enough translation for your report code:

```
YEARS = DateDiff("YYYY",Fields!IssuedOnORNo.Value, Fields!CertificationDate.Value)
MONTHS = (DateDiff("m", Fields!IssuedOnORNo.Value, Fields!CertificationDate.Value)
    - ((DateDiff("m", Fields!IssuedOnORNo.Value, Fields!CertificationDate.Value) / 12) * 12))
DAYS = ((DateDiff("dd", Fields!IssuedOnORNo.Value, Fields!CertificationDate.Value) - ((DateDiff("dd", Fields!IssuedOnORNo.Value, Fields!CertificationDate.Value) / 365) * 365))
        - (((DateDiff("m", Fields!IssuedOnORNo.Value, Fields!CertificationDate.Value) - ((DateDiff("m", Fields!IssuedOnORNo.Value, Fields!CertificationDate.Value) / 12) * 12))) * 30) - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks but I think I cannot use it in RDLC code property. I would like the rdlc to compute the two dates which will produce it could be years or months or days old of the baby.

Comment: thank you. Is there any way I can make it inside the code property of RDLC report in visual studio? I also use this property in appending th,nd,rd and st in day dates of the certificate and it works. So I believe computing age in years months days can be done also here.

Comment: have you tried putting the code as a formula on a table cell?